# Не получается написать код

Tags: c++

Можете помочь с данным заданием?
В  строке  указать  слово,  в  котором  количество  гласных  букв минимально.
С использованием массива символов.

Вот начало кода, дальше идей нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int count1 = 11;
    char vowels[] = "eyuoaEYUOA";
    char text[100];
    gets_s(text);
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(text); j++)
        {
            if (text[i] != vowels[j])
            {
                count++;
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Хотела подсчитать количество гласных букв, а потом сравнить с гласными буквами, которые заданы в массиве `vowels`, затем `count1` присвоить значение `count`, если `count` меньше, а затем вывести `text[i]`, но выводится только первый элемент массива `text`.

Comment: Можем помочь, начинай делать, будут конкретные проблемы - задавай конкретные вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что всё не так сложно:

1. В массив символов добавляем все гласные буквы алфавита.
2. Из строки выбираем первое слово (разделяем слова по пробелам).
3. Пишем количество гласных букв в слове в отдельную переменную типа `int` (сравниваем каждую букву слова с каждым из элементов массива).
4. В строковую переменную записываем это слово.
5. Переходим к следующему слову, если количество гласных букв меньше, то в строковую переменную записываем это слово.
6. Выводим строку.

Comment: а как выбрать слово из строки?

Comment: @desuchhan, надо найти его начало, а потом перебирать символы, пока не встретится пробел (или конец строки)

Comment: Началом слова можно считать первую букву после пробела.